# urlFetch terms of service and quotas - using Google Docs to monitor website uptime

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I've been making improvements to a Google Docs spreadsheet (and the underlying script) that monitors websites for uptime/downtime. You can see a description and copy the spreadsheet here: http://agileadam.com/google-docs-uptime-monitor

I'm a web developer and need to monitor the uptime of 199 (the number will grow) websites. This is an accumulation of many years of development - all sites we control. So, I had a 5 minute time-driven trigger that ran my function, which loops through every URL and checks the HTTP status using urlFetch.

I have two questions:

1. Is this a violation of the Google Docs TOS?
2. At 5:57am I got a message: "Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch." According to https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard the limit is 20,000 for my account. According to my calculations I should have only been around 14,000 uses. Why did it bomb out on me?

I am going to remove many of the domain names that are similar (I suppose I don't NEED to monitor .com and .org for the same site) and I've changed my trigger to run every 15 minutes. This will reduce the number of executions considerably.